# Have not gotten any notice about 100K swag

Tags: support, reputation, swag

I've recently passed 100K reputation on SO, but have not gotten any email or message about possibly getting SO swag. Would appreciate some help with that (possibly even the email of a person to ask).

Comment: Related: *[State of the Stack: a new quarterly update on community and product](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/03/10/state-of-the-stack-community-product-q1-2021/)* - *"We announced that we are bringing back swag for users and are hard at work right now making that a reality."* (2021-03-10)

Comment: Your account history says you were sent the 100k email on April 4. That email doesn't explicitly mention swag (yet), but is used to put you on the list of eligible people for the CM team to reach out to. Past that, there is no other process - you just have to wait until they get around to processing another batch. I'll leave thee CM team to answer because I'm no longer involved with that process at all.

Comment: @animuson: Thank you for the clarification. I couldn't find that email, or an indication it was sent to me on Apr 4th, but - ok, I guess I'll just wait patiently.

Comment: Check which email is linked to your SO profile, and make sure you double-check your spam folder.

Comment: Note that depending on your spam folder settings, the email may already have been deleted if it went to the spam folder

Comment: @CodyGray: I'll double-check.

Comment: @animuson I was sent a swag email from Community Swag <communityswag@stackoverflowsolutions.com>  on Wed, 13 Oct 2021 and filled in the form. I've yet to receive anything :/

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine: I double-checked my Junk and Trash folder on TB, and didn't see anything there, although I guess it's not impossible I had inadvertently cleared the Junk folder early this month.

Comment: Related (updated 2022-05-03): [Swag is coming back! (temporarily paused)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358195/)